# Can I use PGP to encrypt plain text just like AES does?

Tags: c#, encryption, pgp

I want to know if [PGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) encryption can be used to encrypt plain text just like the other encryption types(AES,3DES). Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Someone can tell me what do I need to change in my question? So it can be understandable.

Comment: It might help to show what code and research you have tried and specifically where you are getting stuck. [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) gives a more detailed outline of asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

OpenPGP is an encryption scheme, which uses encryption algorithms (you named AES, 3DES) and adds other stuff besides the encryption itself. So OpenPGP is wider, than AES.

Plain text is just a human-readable "form" of certain binary data, so you would have no problems encrypting the plain text. The question is what you want to get as a result. OpenPGP would give you the binary data, or, when so-called Armoring is enabled, you will get the data in text format as well.

Comment: Hi @Eugene , So it can be used to encrypt plain text that store in variable in c# to encrypt?

Comment: @janmvtrinidad Yes, of course. You would need to convert the Unicode string to the binary data in some encoding (say UTF8 or UTF16), then encrypt the resulting buffer.

Comment: Hi, can you provide a working example for this? Thanks!

Comment: @janmvtrinidad our SecureBlackbox includes samples for OpenPGP operations, and we provide support via our forum. As for other pgp libraries, if any, - they have their own support rules and I don't know them or the code of their libraries.

Comment: HI, Thanks for the info, I will check it.